# How to change a particular value when I select a date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tapestry

The requirement is I have two date fields:

- One is effective date and date of birth. When I select the effective date on the page.
  The age field should do the following calculation.
  That is age would be Effective date - date of birth. the result should be set to the age field.

How to do in javascript or JQuery?

I'm using tapestry front end. So in the HTML page I want to do this setting of value to age field.

Comment: add a fiddle, with whatever you are using as library.

Comment: jquery datepicker should work

Comment: Show what you have already tried, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your dates into milliseconds and subtract them, then calculate the age.

HTML

```
<input type="date" id="effective" />
<input type="date" id="born" />
```

jQuery

```
function getTime(date){
    var dateArr = date.split('-');
    return new Date(dateArr[0], dateArr[1], dateArr[2]).getTime();
}
function calcDate(date1,date2) {
    var eff_date = getTime(date1);
    var born_date = getTime(date2);

    var diff = Math.floor(eff_date - born_date);

    var day = 1000* 60 * 60 * 24;

    var days = Math.floor(diff/day);
    var months = Math.floor(days/31);
    var years = Math.floor(months/12);
    return years
}

$("input[type=date]").change(function(){
    if($("#effective").val() != "" && $("#born").val() != ""){
        var age = calcDate($("#effective").val(),$("#born").val())
        alert(age);
    }
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ormdan2d/)..